# Issue with creating new instance of can for STM32F429 Discovery board in rust when using stm32f4xx_hal

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, can-bus, stm32f4discovery

Problem while executing the example file can-send.rs from the stm32f4xx_hal crate [`https://github.com/stm32-rs/stm32f4xx-hal/blob/master/examples/can-send.rs`]
for stm32f429 Discovery board, cannot find any way to instantiate can using new(), the compiler shows error saying there is no such function like new().
I have been facing this issue since a while. It would be great if you could help.

The error log is like this:

```
          let can = dp.CAN1.can((tx, rx));
|                           ^^^ method not found in `CAN1`
```

I wanted to initialize the can bus however there seems to be a problem doing that. This is from the stm32f4xx_hal examples

```
    use panic_halt as _;

    use bxcan::filter::Mask32;
    use bxcan::{Fifo, Frame, StandardId};
    use cortex_m_rt::entry;
    use nb::block;
    use stm32f4xx_hal::{pac, prelude::*};

    #[entry]
    fn main() -> ! {
    let dp = pac::Peripherals::take().unwrap();

    let rcc = dp.RCC.constrain();

    // To meet CAN clock accuracy requirements an external crystal or ceramic
    // resonator must be used. The blue pill has a 8MHz external crystal.
    // Other boards might have a crystal with another frequency or none at all.
    rcc.cfgr.use_hse(8.MHz()).freeze();

    let gpiob = dp.GPIOB.split();
    let mut can1 = {
        let rx = gpiob.pb8.into_alternate::<9>();
        let tx = gpiob.pb9.into_alternate::<9>();

        // let can = Can::new(dp.CAN1, (tx, rx));
        // or
        let can = dp.CAN1.can((tx, rx));

        bxcan::Can::builder(can)
            // APB1 (PCLK1): 8MHz, Bit rate: 500kBit/s, Sample Point 87.5%
            // Value was calculated with http://www.bittiming.can-wiki.info/
            .set_bit_timing(0x001c_0000)
            .enable()
    };
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Removed the image.

Comment: Just by enabling the "can" feature in cargo.toml solves this issue. :)

Comment: Next time, try these questions on the ST forum, you will likely get more support there. https://community.st.com/s/